# Positioning an Entity in a Class (Pygame)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to blit an image of grass onto my game in a specific area, but I'm having trouble doing so because it's in a class. I want to do something like this..

```
grass_platform.draw(screen, (200, 200))
```

NOTE: I know this actually doesn't work

Here's my code...

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#Screen Size
screen_size = [1024,576]

#Display Window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('The Adventures of Fresco the Explorer')

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#Game Start
gameStart = False

#Backgrounds
forest = pygame.image.load('forest.png')

#Gravity
gravity =-10
fall = True

#Player
fresco = pygame.image.load('fresco v2.png').convert()
fresco = pygame.transform.scale(fresco,(32,136))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = fresco
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update (self):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.rect.x -= 6
                self.image = pygame.transform.flip(fresco, True, False)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                self.rect.x += 6
                self.image = pygame.transform.flip(fresco, False, False)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                self.rect.y -= 20

    def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

player = Player(0, 0, 'fresco v2.png')

#Grass Platform
grass = pygame.image.load('grass.png')
grass = pygame.transform.scale(grass, (90, 90))

class Grass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, filename):

        self.image = grass
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

grass_platform = Grass('grass.png')

#Game Loop
while not gameStart:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameStart = True

    #Background Blitted
    screen.blit(forest,(0,0))

    #Falling Event
    if fall == True:
        if gravity:
            player.rect.y -= gravity

    #Class Blitted
    player.update()
    player.draw(screen)
    grass_platform.draw(screen)

    #Updates Screen
    pygame.display.update()

    #FPS
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: in `__init__` you need `self.rect.x = x` and `self.rect.y = y`

Comment: to make code more readable put all classes at the beginning. And use loaded image as argument ie. `Grass(grass)` or load image inside class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if i understood you correctly but if you mean just passing a coordinate parameter and blitting to that position that should be quite easy.

```
class Grass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, filename):

        self.image = grass
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def draw(self, screen, pos):
        screen.blit(self.image, pos)
```

and then when you draw() you just do this:

```
grass_platform.draw(screen, (300, 200))
```

or on the other hand if you want to keep the position you could add
this code to the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, filename, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

and then acces it later

```
def draw(self, screen):
    window.blit(img, (self.x, self.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- `Player` and `Grass` are subclasses from `Sprite`, so they have already a draw function which does exactly what you are doing. Just remove them.
- the following part

  ```
  #Falling Event
  if fall == True:
      if gravity:
          player.rect.y -= gravity
  ```

  is specific to the `Player` class and should be moved to the `Player` class' update function
- When using the `Sprite` class, the `rect` attribute is used to store the position of the sprite, hence the `x` and `y` attribute in your `Player` class don't make much sense. Remove them, and use the `x` and `y` parameters to change the `x` and `y` attribute of the `rect` instead:

  ```
  self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
  ```
- Hence, if you want to draw `grass_platform` at a specific position, just alter it's `rect`, e.g.:

  ```
  grass_platform.rect.topleft = (200, 200)
  ```
- instead of calling `draw` and `update` on each of your sprites manually, just but them into a [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), and call `draw` and `update` on that `Group`.